# How to add/run Hiero in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, libgdx

How can I add/install/run Hiero?

I have created a libgdx project using the installer from http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/download.html and the Gradle extension for Eclipse (I have never used Gradle before).

From : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Hiero

> If you are using Gradle, you can easily run Hiero from your IDE.
>
> Example for IntelliJ IDEA: Go to the Hiero class, right click and select Run Hiero.main(). On the Run >configurations popup that will appear, select the Desktop module, and click Run.

How do you do this under Eclipse?

> java -cp gdx.jar;gdx-natives.jar;gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar;gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar;extensions\gdx-tools\gdx-tools.jar com.badlogic.gdx.tools.hiero.Hiero

I tried that, but "com.badlogic.gdx.tools.hiero.Hiero" was not found.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you got the error message:

> "com.badlogic.gdx.tools.hiero.Hiero" was not found.

Then most likely you didn't add the libgdx tools extension in your gradle dependencies. Add this to the desktop dependencies:

```
 compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
```

see the [libgdx gradle wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Dependency-management-with-Gradle#tools-gradle) for more detailed instructions.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, right-click on your desktop project -> Run As -> Android Application.  In the menu that pops up, select Hiero, and voila!